# Write Excel with PDF x & y coordinates values

Tags: java, excel, pdfbox

I am new to this java world. Using PDFBox PrintTextlocations i am able to read x & y coordinates values from the PDF file using below code.

```
public class PrintTextLocations extends PDFTextStripper {

public PrintTextLocations() throws IOException {
    super.setSortByPosition(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    PDDocument document = null;
    try {
        File input = new File("abcdef.pdf");
        document = PDDocument.load(input);
        if (document.isEncrypted()) {
            document.decrypt("");
        }
        PrintTextLocations printer = new PrintTextLocations();
        List allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        for (int i = 0; i < allPages.size(); i++) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);
            System.out.println("Processing page: " + i);
            PDStream contents = page.getContents();
            if (contents != null) {
                printer.processStream(page, page.findResources(), page.getContents().getStream());
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (document != null) {
            document.close();
        }
    }
}
@Override 
protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
    System.out.println("String[X:" + text.getXDirAdj() +  ", Y:"  + text.getYDirAdj() + 
            " fs=" + text.getFontSize() + 
            " xscale=" + text.getXScale() + 
            " height=" + text.getHeightDir() + 
            " space="  + text.getWidthOfSpace() + 
            " width="  + text.getWidthDirAdj() + 
            "]" + text.getCharacter());
}
 }
```

By Googling I got above Code. Now i got Console output as below.

```
Processing page: 0
String[X:453.9598, Y:155.16022 fs=13.92 xscale=13.89324 height=10.523516 space=3.8623211 width=9.266785]S
String[X:463.19983, Y:155.16022 fs=13.92 xscale=13.89324 height=7.7951965 space=3.8623211 width=7.72464]a
String[X:470.99982, Y:155.16022 fs=13.92 xscale=13.89324 height=9.994557 space=3.8623211 width=3.8623352]l
String[X:474.8398, Y:155.16022 fs=13.92 xscale=13.89324 height=7.7951965 space=3.8623211 width=7.72464]e
String[X:482.63977, Y:155.16022 fs=13.92 xscale=13.89324 height=7.7951965 space=3.8623211 width=7.72464]s
String[X:490.43976, Y:155.16022 fs=13.92 xscale=13.89324 height=0.0 space=3.8623211 width=3.8623352] 
String[X:494.27975, Y:155.16022 fs=13.92 xscale=13.89324 height=1.8095994 space=3.8623211 width=4.6264343]-
String[X:498.95978, Y:155.16022 fs=13.92 xscale=13.89324 height=0.0 space=3.8623211 width=3.8623352]
```

My issue is, Using above x & y values how can i write the values into the Excel Sheet. I need to insert at the exact place according to the PDF Format. kindly help me out. thnks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to write Excel sheet using above x & Y cordinates...??

Comment: Excel isn't for writing stuff at a specific coordinate. Use a graphic format, e.g. PDF.

Comment: But seriously - maybe tell what you really want to do. Is it the good old "I want to convert a PDF table (e.g. an invoice) into an excel sheet"?

Comment: well, similar to that. just i need to keep pdf format in excel sheet. so i am trying through x & y coordinates. it is possible can u guide me with proper link or snippet. thnks

Comment: You can't, unless you use heuristics.

Comment: thnks for your valuable reply. let me try out heuristics.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thnks for your valuable reply.  just one clarification. using above console output how can i create template using java....??

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Template of what? If you want to know how to create and manipulate an excel file, use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).